# How do you use GULP on a Plesk server?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, plesk, plesk-onyx

I'm using the https://github.com/roots/sage/tree/8.5.4 theme, which uses gulp watch to compile the CSS.

It was originally developed on a local machine, so everything is setup for it to compile, but I'm trying to get gulp watch to run on the server.

Does any know how to get gulp working via Plesk command line or any other way?

Comment: https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/reseller-guide/website-management/nodejs-support.76652/